# Using any() in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

In the following dataframe, I would like to delete pairs of rows that have the same values for `ITEM_ID` and `VALUE`, but where one has `TYPE == 'O'` (for 'outbound') and the other has `TYPE == 'I'` (for 'inbound', comes later):

```
        Date        ITEM_ID TYPE VALUE
236656  2012-02-28  ECE240  O    1.0
242962  2012-03-02  ECE240  O    1.0
248720  2012-03-06  ECE240  O    1.0 (remove - out)
226194  2012-03-19  ECE240  I    1.0 (remove - in)
263320  2012-03-20  ECE240  O    1.0 (remove - out)
242977  2012-03-24  ECE240  I    1.0 (remove - in)
209713  2012-03-31  ECE240  O    1.0
279806  2012-04-06  ECE240  O    1.0
277213  2012-04-08  ECE240  O    1.0
288865  2012-04-17  ECE240  O    3.0
290041  2012-04-20  ECE240  O    2.0 (remove - out)
136730  2012-04-22  ECE240  I    2.0 (remove - in)
295236  2012-04-24  ECE240  O    1.0
292597  2012-04-30  ECE240  O    1.0
313503  2012-05-14  ECE240  O    1.0
314786  2012-05-15  ECE240  O    2.0
318277  2012-05-20  ECE240  O    1.0 (remove - out)
328787  2012-06-01  ECE240  O    2.0
2134    2012-06-16  ECE240  I    1.0 (remove - in)
343138  2012-06-17  ECE240  O    2.0
343139  2012-06-22  ECE240  O    1.0
346935  2012-06-29  ECE240  O    1.0
215777  2012-07-06  ECE240  O    1.0
356292  2012-07-06  ECE240  O    2.0
261989  2012-07-21  ECE240  O    2.0
```

Code:

```
df  = df.sort_values(by = ['ITEM_ID ', 'Date'])
df1 = df.groupby(['ITEM_ID ','VALUE']).filter(lambda x : ~(x['TYPE'].eq('I') & x['TYPE'].shift().eq('O')).any())
df1
```

which returned:

```
        Date        ITEM_ID TYPE    VALUE
288865  2012-04-17  ECE240  O       3.0
```

This is not what I wanted, as I was expecting only 4 pairs to be removed (labelled in `df` above).
The expected output:

```
        Date        ITEM_ID TYPE VALUE
236656  2012-02-28  ECE240  O    1.0
242962  2012-03-02  ECE240  O    1.0


209713  2012-03-31  ECE240  O    1.0
279806  2012-04-06  ECE240  O    1.0
277213  2012-04-08  ECE240  O    1.0
288865  2012-04-17  ECE240  O    3.0
 

295236  2012-04-24  ECE240  O    1.0
292597  2012-04-30  ECE240  O    1.0
313503  2012-05-14  ECE240  O    1.0
314786  2012-05-15  ECE240  O    2.0

328787  2012-06-01  ECE240  O    2.0

343138  2012-06-17  ECE240  O    2.0
343139  2012-06-22  ECE240  O    1.0
346935  2012-06-29  ECE240  O    1.0
215777  2012-07-06  ECE240  O    1.0
356292  2012-07-06  ECE240  O    2.0
261989  2012-07-21  ECE240  O    2.0
```

In Python docs it states for `any()`:

> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False.

I think it removed all "groups" of rows where `TYPE==I` for a row and all other rows where `VALUE` is the same and `TYPE==O`. How can I remove only one pair for each "group" (i.e., for each row with `TYPE==I`, only one row in front with `TYPE==O`)?

---

[EDIT 1]

I also tried:

```
df  = df.sort_values(by = ['ITEM_ID', 'Date'])
df1 = df.groupby(['ITEM_ID','VALUE']).filter(lambda x : ~(x['TYPE'].eq('I') & (x['TYPE'].shift().eq('O'))))
df1
```

which caught error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-935-65eda184ce24> in <module>
      1 df= df.sort_values(by = ['ITEM_ID', 'Date'])
----> 2 df1= df.groupby(['ITEM_ID','VALUE']).filter(lambda x : ~(x['TYPE'].eq('I') & (x['TYPE'].shift().eq('O'))))
      3 df1

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in filter(self, func, dropna, *args, **kwargs)
   1594                 # non scalars aren't allowed
   1595                 raise TypeError(
-> 1596                     f"filter function returned a {type(res).__name__}, "
   1597                     "but expected a scalar bool"
   1598                 )

TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool
```

---

[EDIT 2]

For the following dataframe:

```
        Date        ITEM_ID TYPE    VALUE
342874  2012-06-18  ECE240  O       1.0 (not removed - out)
342415  2012-06-18  ECE240  O       25.0
325718  2012-06-18  ECE240  O       1.0 (not removed - out)
334488  2012-06-18  ECE240  O       1.0 (not removed - out)
342412  2012-06-18  ECE240  O       25.0
341634  2012-06-18  ECE240  O       9.0
341996  2012-06-19  ECE240  O       2.0 (remove - out)
341747  2012-06-19  ECE240  O       1.0 (remove - out)
272185  2012-06-24  ECE240  I       1.0 (remove - in)
219     2012-06-24  ECE240  I       1.0 (not removed - in)
6896    2012-06-24  ECE240  I       2.0 (remove - in)
351560  2012-06-24  ECE240  O       1.0 (remove - out)
312636  2012-06-26  ECE240  I       1.0 (remove - in)
2376    2012-06-30  ECE240  I       1.0 (not removed - in)
350922  2012-07-02  ECE240  O       1.0 (remove - out)
270589  2012-07-09  ECE240  I       4.0
331689  2012-07-15  ECE240  I       1.0 (remove - in)
299912  2012-07-23  ECE240  I       1.0 (not removed - in) 
212418  2012-07-23  ECE240  I       3.0
3992    2012-07-24  ECE240  I       2.0
388937  2012-08-10  ECE240  O       10.0
124596  2012-08-18  ECE240  I       1.0 
368945  2012-08-19  ECE240  O       12.0
368944  2012-08-19  ECE240  O       6.0
239581  2012-08-24  ECE240  I       4.0
```

some rows that also satisfy the conditions are not removed(see dataframe above), because they are not immediately in front of the `TYPE==I` row. To clear all the rows including these ones, I think I could run the code repeatedly until these rows are exhausted. I'm wondering if there is another way to do it?

Comment: Maybe try placing the iterable inside the any() function instead of chaining the any to the end of it

Comment: Hi @SGolds it caught error `TypeError: filter function returned a int, but expected a scalar bool`

Comment: If the TYPE=='O' row comes first and TYPE=='I' comes second, should that be dropped or not? Or are you saying it's assured that order can never happen?

Comment: for the below 3 rows, do you want to delete 2 of them? `236656  2012-02-28  ECE240  O    1.0
242962  2012-03-02  ECE240  O    1.0
248720  2012-03-06  ECE240  O    1.0 (remove - out)` or do you want to delete only the one marked as `remove-out`

Comment: Hi @smci `TYPE=='O' ` followed by `TYPE=='I'`is the usual case. The opposite case could be ignored.

Comment: Don't phrase your question about a specific function like `any()`. Best to ask about your intent *"Delete grouped rows paired on field where they differ"*, or something.

Comment: Hi @JoeFerndz I would like to remove the pair of `248720  2012-03-06  ECE240  O    1.0 (remove - out)
226194  2012-03-19  ECE240  I    1.0 (remove - in)`. So each `TYPE==I` should match to a `TYPE==O` that has happened before it.

Comment: @smci good idea, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason using `filter` with `groupby` doesn't work is that pandas expects a single boolean return value for each group. If that values is true, then the whoel group will be removed.

Instead, what you want to do here is remove individual rows within the groups. A possible solution would be to simply use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to create a boolean mask:

```
mask = df.sort_values('Date')\
  .groupby(['ITEM_ID', 'VALUE'])['TYPE']\
  .apply(lambda x: ((x == 'O') & (x.shift(-1) == 'I')) | (x == 'I') & (x.shift(1) == 'O'))
df.loc[~mask]
```

This will return the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful answer - this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @nilsinelabore: Happy to help =)

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to change the condition to: for each `TYPE==I`, consider all rows prior that has `TYPE==O` and same `VALUE`, and pick the most recent row, delete the pair(that is, not just `x.shift(1)` but indefinite number of shifts before the current `TYPE==I`).

Comment: @nilsinelabore: If it possible to have consecutive `I`s? Otherwise there should be no difference in the result.

Comment: Yes it's possible. For instance, if there are four consecutive rows of `TYPE ==I`, would it delete the correct number of rows, ie., 8 rows in total? Or does it only remove one `TYPE==O`?

Comment: @nilsinelabore, since you are sorting the data by `Date`, the data is going to be the immediate one above it. So aren't you already getting what you want? Is there something else you are looking for? If so, can you share in desired output as example so we can try to address it.

Comment: @JoeFerndz please see `EDIT 2`.

Comment: @nilsinelabore: I can't find some smart way to do it when there are consecutive `I`s. One way would be as you say, to iteratively run the length of the dataframe doesn't change. Another would be to use `groupby.apply` and handle each group one-by-one, there would probably need to be some sort of iterative deletion or some recursion needed inside the applied function though. You could try to ask a new question for this issue and see if there is someone else with a better idea.

Comment: Hi Shaido, I found a way to do it with a while loop. Thank you for your help:)

Comment: @nilsinelabore: Nice, happy you managed to solve it :)